# crystal reports specified argument was out of the range of valid values

Tags: c#, parameters, crystal-reports

I am Creating a Crystal report,Created Parameter Values.
In c# while i Adding Parameter to the Crystal, i'm getting the following error
if i use Dataset instead of query in the report then it was working fine.but if i remove the dataset then getting error.
this is my code:

```
  AddParameterToReport("ReportType", ReportType);
  AddParameterToReport("DocumentID", VoucherId.ToString());
 public void AddParameterToReport(string CRParamName, string CRParamValue)
        {
            try
            {
                ParameterFields parameterFields = CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo;
                ParameterValues currentParameterValues = new ParameterValues();
                ParameterDiscreteValue parameterDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

                parameterDiscreteValue.Value = CRParamValue;
                currentParameterValues.Add(parameterDiscreteValue);

                ParameterField parameterField = parameterFields[CRParamName];
                parameterField.CurrentValues = currentParameterValues;
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                mobjGenlib.SendLogText(ee.ToString(), "FrmReportCR.aspx.cs", "AddParameterToReport()");
            }
        }
```

[image]

can any one help me where i'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use Set not Add to set the parameter value in the report, and you can replace it with the Method

Like:

```
ReportObject.SetParameterValue("Parameter Name In The Report", Report Parameter Value)
```